# How to solve an abstract model using Pyomo in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, pyomo

I am learning how to use Pyomo in Google Colab and I created an Abstract model, but I dont know the coding to read the data file and solve the model. The documentation gives instructions about the command prompt but it is not the case as I am working with Google Colab.

I will highly appreaciate your help.

Comment: My 2 cents:  If you are just getting started, make `ConcreteModels`  It is almost always easier and if the data is too large to hand-jam in, use regular python to read the data source(s) and still build a `ConcreteModel` from that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My model has many data so a ConcreteModel is not useful. In addition, my current computer doesn't have capacity to support Python directly so I need to use Google Colab

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install pyomo 
from pyomo.environ import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
!wget -N -q "https://ampl.com/dl/open/ipopt/ipopt-linux64.zip"
!unzip -o -q ipopt-linux64

model = AbstractModel()
model.x = Var(bounds=(0,1.2), within=Reals)
model.obj1 = Objective(expr=model.x**2, sense=maximize)
#opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')
opt=SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='/content/ipopt')
instance = model.create_instance()
results = opt.solve(instance) # solves and updates instance
print('OF= ',value(instance.obj1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After using a data file .dat with the info of my parameters, the following error appears: 

ValueError: No variables appear in the Pyomo model constraints or objective. This is not supported by the NL file interface

The file .dat has the following structure:

set I := 1 ;
set J := 1 2 ;

param a :=
1 1 3
1 2 4
;

param c:=
1 2
2 3
;

param b := 1 1 ;

end ;